# How to update Highcharts combination chart based on hover event

Tags: highcharts

I am using a Highchart similar to http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo.

I would like to update the data in the pie chart in a combination chart when a **column** series from the column chart is hovered over.

Is there a way to do that? I haven't found the documentation on highcharts events that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data points in your series can have a mouseOver event handler attached to them. This handler can then update tHe series data in the pie.

```
Series.data.events
```

This is the example of using the mouseOver event:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-mouseover/

In the event handler, you need to set the series data for the pie.